# Why is Visual Studio not compiling without Administrator rights anymore

Tags: visual-studio-2015, compiler-errors, compilation

Visual Studio 2015 is not compiling without administrator rights anymore. If I start without admin rights, I get the "There were build errors. Would you like to continue..." message. If I then click "No" to see the errors, there are none.

If I do this as an administrator, it works fine, and it has worked fine before. The folder I'm building in is owned by my current account and I set Full Control to all users on this PC (i.e. including my current account) in the file permissions.

I'm not sure what I did to disable Visual Studio to write files (which is at least what I guess is the problem). I have installed MSBuildTools, Windows SDK 8.1 and 10 yesterday and added environment variables for MSBuild.exe, so maybe there was some problem there. Otherwise I have not (knowingly) touched the files or folders which are build (into) by my current project.

My question is obviously how to solve this or where else to look for rights I need to set?

About the building of my current project: It is C# (.NET) code that builds into a .dll which is used by a program which is also used to debug. The .dll is outputed into the current projects folder though, not in said programs bin folder.

**EDIT**
So far I've tried the following, none of which worked:

1. Use the repair function of Visual Studio 2015
2. Uninstall and reinstall Visual Studio 2015
3. Delete and recreate the Project Folder
4. Claim Ownership of the Project Folder and (trying to) revoke the Read-Only attribute
5. Reinstalling the program that is started for debugging
6. Delete the (manually added) environment variable for MSBuild

What did work was manually compiling the solution (I think it was the MSBuild command prompt, but it may have been the development command prompt), although I'm not entirely sure this was done without admin rights automatically being granted to said command prompt. In any case, this should not be the standard behaviour or workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the MSBuild.exe was set to always start as Administrator. Since VS itself was not starting as an administrator, I guess it didn't have permission to start MSBuild.exe. This would also explain why I could compile if Visual Studio was started with administrator rights.

The solution was thus just to revoke the checkmark of start as administrator in the MSBuild.exe properties.